# Why doesn't Ubuntu constantly run my hard drive like Windows does?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, hard-drive, windows-10

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and Xubuntu 14.04. I've noticed that when Windows boots, the hard drive indicator LED on my laptop immediately starts going, and doesn't stop until about 10 minutes after I sign in. When Ubuntu boots, however, the light flutters a bit, and then only goes on when I'm reading or writing to files, or occasionally when (I assume) background processes are doing so.

Does Ubuntu just utilize my RAM better than Windows? Is Windows doing something that Ubuntu does not do when I sign in? Is this caused by the difference in the file systems? Does the indicator light mean something different in Ubuntu than in Windows?

I don't think it's the last one, because I can also hear the hard drive almost constantly spinning (yes, it's the hard drive, not the fan) when Windows is running, but I hardly notice a peep out of it with Ubuntu. What's going on here?

Comment: What do you have running at startup in Windows?

Comment: Nothing that I can disable. It's pretty much a clean install. One of the new bugs... erm... "features" of Windows 10 is that it doesn't allow you to prevent some "important system tasks" from running at startup. Most of it's to do with the new Apple-style Windows Update. I had the same experience with Windows 8 and 8.1, though. They each had nothing huge running at startup, and still used the hard drive (or at least the indicator and the motor) a lot more than Ubuntu.

Comment: I have just noticed this too. I only boot into win 8.1 very infrequently now, and the "C" drive runs, maxed out, from when I log in for about 30 minutes.  Nothing like this happens with Ubuntu.  However, I fear this is really a Windows question, not well suited for this site.

Comment: Windows has a number of tasks which may or may not be running, depending upon what in the world you have told it.  Some possibilities include disk indexing, and AV scanning.  Either way, this is really a Windows question, as opposed to an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Ubuntu also has a number of tasks that may or may not be running, depending on what I've told it ;) I thought I'd ask here to be sure of how Ubuntu uses the hard drive indicator; what it generally does /doesn't do at startup; whether the filesystem it uses could affect the drive use or indicators... @Byte Commander answered the Ubuntu parts of my question. I'll post to Super User and link to helpful answers here for future readers.

Comment: Long story short, Ubuntu isn't crammed full of useless startup tasks and background tasks, which is also why it's faster.

Comment: So, you're asking, why Windows does something that results in dis activity, while Ubuntu does nothing under similar circumstances. Sounds like your question is about Windows.

Comment: No, I'm asking if Ubuntu does what Windows does, and whether the way it uses the hardware is different. The word "why" is not in my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't hear the HDD "spinning", because it spins at a constant rate of usually either 5600 or 7200 rpm and is usually barely audible. What can be loud and is often noticed are the actuator (the "arm" on which the read/write heads are located that move over the platter) movements. And those movements only happen when data needs to read from or written to different cylinders of the disk.

[image: from Wikipedia]

However, the used file system may actually cause a different in the actuator sounds! Ubuntu uses `ext4`, which starts in the middle of a partition to store data and then continues in direction of the borders. It leaves space between the files to allow them to grow without getting fragmented. All in all, the `ext4` file system is designed to minimize fragmentation (file fragments being spread over the whole disk instead of being located in one sequence) and head/actuator movements, so this does not only make it faster but also quieter than Windows' `ntfs`, which starts at the partition beginning and always stuffs file fragments into the leftmost available holes.

So from the behaviour you describe we can say that something on Windows constantly accesses the HDD, while on Ubuntu there is no such process.

I would strongly suspect your Windows Antivirus program which performs any kind of on-idle background scanning, or the search index updater, or anything like that. To determine the exact cause is however a Windows-only question and therefore topic of [Super User](https://www.superuser.com).

On Ubuntu, there just don't run any of such tasks by default. We do not come with Antivirus software by default, and our ClamAV does not have any live protection but only scans on command.

Comment: Thank you. This answers the Ubuntu side of my question. I'll post a question to Super User and edit this question with a link to it for future seekers.

Comment: Woohoo! Welcome to 10K! (and nice answer: great pic!)

Comment: @Fabby That's borrowed from wikipedia. :)